# How to pass data from Parent window to pop-up window

Tags: javascript

parent window is : `http://localhost:8080/webApp/index.html`  by clicking on given Button, a pop-up window appears and i want to send some data as innerHTML from parent window to pop-up window.
i am using below function to appear the pop-up window

```
<script type = text/javascript>
     window.open("popup.html", "popup",'toolbar = no, status = no beforeShow');
</script>
```

popup window url is : `http://localhost:8080/webApp/popup.html`

Now i want to send data (`innerHTML text)` from parent window to popup window and i know it can be post to server using `AJAX` and then add into popup page, But i do not want to send this innerHTML text (data) to server, I just want to use js function to perform my task at client side only. Is it possible?

```
server side : java, servlet
Client Side : jQuery, javascript
```

Comment: People hate pop-ups.  Many browsers and plugins auto-remove pop-ups.  If you can do whatever you're doing without a pop-up it will cause a lot less grief in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
parent window js :  window.open("popup.html", "popup",'toolbar = no, status = no beforeShow');

children/pop-up window js : window.opener.document.getElementById("parent_window_id").innerHTML;
```

Normally you can not access any function or data of parent window from Child/popup window unless you use window.opener = parent window (this is just reference of parent window) and then get any id, function or data(innerHTML)

Answer (score 4):

why not try simple window handler like:

```
x = window.open("....","..","...");
x.document.write("bla bla bla");
```

The idea here is, when we do refer only document.write and other document level command it refers to current window ie. if we say `document.getElementById("xxx")` then its actually for current window like `window.document.getElementById("xxx");` If we want it from popup window then we need to assign a handler for that window using:

```
x = window.open(".....")
```

and we can use that handler to perform as same as in current window. instead of `document.getElementByID` use `x.document.getElementById`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to write like that x.document.getElementById("pop_up_div_id").innerHTML = parent_window_innerHTML.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to pass some data, you can add a global variable to your popup by saving the return value of `window.open` and then setting a property on it. If you want to manipulate the HTML of the popup window, you can create a jQuery object of the popup window's body.

```
var popup = window.open("popup.html", "popup",'toolbar = no, status = no beforeShow');
popup.dataFromParent = 'Some Data';

var $popupBody = $(popup.document.body);
// Manipulate $popupBody just like you would any other jQuery object.
```

Comment: Passing data to the pop up like you are suggesting doesn't seem to work in IE10 is that expected behavior?

Comment: I haven't tried this code specifically in IE10. I don't know if what you're seeing should be expected. Perhaps there's added security in IE10?